# launch another activity on sms receive

Tags: android, android-intent

i am trying to call method [method name is verifyed()] from another activity on receiving sms of specific word (a random 10 latter's) which is stored in string named :- vcode.

```
     public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {
    protected LocationManager locationManager;





public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

     try {


        if (bundle != null) {

            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

SmsMessage currentMessage =     SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
    String phoneNumber =  currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();



    if (message.equals(vcodei)) {
    int durationge = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
  Toast toastge = Toast.makeText(context, "Verifyed ", durationge);
   toastge.show();

   mainpageactivity mp = new mainpageactivity() {
        public void launch() {

            this.verifyed();

     }
   };


   }


  } 

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);
           int durationg = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toastg = Toast.makeText(context,"map error"+ e     , durationg);

                                toastg.show();   
    }


}




}
```

my second activity is as below which i have mentioned imports and the method needs to be called...

```
package com.androidexample.broadcastreceiver;
import com.androidexample.broadcastreceiver.IncomingSms;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Context;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.net.Uri;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.os.Environment;



import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.Window;

import android.view.WindowManager;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.Toast;

import static com.androidexample.broadcastreceiver.BroadcastNewSms.buffer;

import static com.androidexample.broadcastreceiver.IncomingSms.num_buffer;

import static com.androidexample.broadcastreceiver.IncomingSms.vcodei;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.text.DateFormat;

import java.util.Date;

import java.util.List;


 public class mainpageactivity extends Activity {
  public String mobile;
 public String vcode;
  private String log;
   private Button register_btn;
   private EditText countryCode_txt;
 private EditText mobileno_txt;
 private TextView note_txt;
 public EditText name_txt;
  private TextView textView1;
  private TextView textView2;
  private TextView textView3;
   private TextView textView4;
   private TextView textView5;
 DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainpage);

    register_btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_btn);        
    countryCode_txt =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.countryCode_txt);     
    mobileno_txt =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobileno_txt);
    note_txt =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.note_txt);
    textView1 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView2 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView3 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    textView4 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    textView5 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
     name_txt =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_txt);

    public void verifyed() {
      db.addContact(new Contact(name_txt.getText().toString().trim(),mobile));

      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Now what..",


                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

      Intent register = new Intent(mainpageactivity.this, BroadcastNewSms.class);
     startActivity(register);
      mainpageactivity.this.finish();


                }

     }
```

AndroidManifest.xml is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.androidexample.broadcastreceiver"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.androidexample.broadcastreceiver.mainpageactivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.androidexample.broadcastreceiver.IncomingSms">   
        <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


  <activity android:name="BroadcastNewSms" ></activity>  
</application>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

please reply with your valuable help...
i am new in android..

Thanks

Comment: Have you set the receiver in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: i do receive sms and successfully and onrecieve code executes successfully Toast gets visible on sms recieve...  i ll post my AndroidManifest.xml... please check if i am missing somthing in it... thanks

Comment: check my answer. Anyway, your code is not following Java naming conventions and formatting. I suggest you clean up your code and invest time in some Java basics.

Comment: You don't write what doesn't work :-) You should add some more explanations.

Answer (score 0):

To start an activity, you should use `Context.startActivity(intent)`. See full code below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,mainpageactivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thsnks for your reply. the method named verified is not calling... am i correct with below code?


    if (message.equals(vcodei)) {
    int durationge = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
     Toast toastge = Toast.makeText(context, "Verifyed ", durationge);
     toastge.show();


     // till here code executes properly

      mainpageactivity mp = new mainpageactivity() {
        
      public void launch() {

            this.verifyed();   // proble in calling this method

     }
    };

Comment: The code is wrong. After `toastge.show()`, put the above two lines and remove the rest

Answer (score 0):

you keep your broadcast receiver as it is, and you add a broadcast intent in it , in place of this:

```
mainpageactivity mp = new mainpageactivity() {
    public void launch() {

        this.verifyed();

 }
```

you delete that and you put this code:

```
            // this intent will call the activity whih will lunch your methode
            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
            broadcastIntent.setAction("com.appname.SMS_RECU");

            context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

Then in your activity, you define your  receiver and intentFilter, directly after the activity definition:

```
SmsReceiver broadcastReceiver;  

IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
```

Then you instantiate your receiver, in onCreat:

```
broadcastReceiver = new SmsReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                    /*you call your methode*/
                verifyed();
            }
        };
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

you creat also an intentFilter which will be called by the broadcastReceiver, in onCreat:

```
intentFilter.addAction("com.appname.SMS_RECU");
```

you register your receiver, in onResume:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
}
```

you unregister your receiver, in onPause:

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
            unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
```

delete the receiver and the intentFilter that you added in your manifest.xml, you don't need  it anymore.
I hope it will work for you.